# iOS -touch events in a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with a number of rows. When selecting a row, it expands/collapses, by increasing the height of the row.

Now my question is, how do I only make the 'select' action apply to a certain rect? For example, if each row in my tableview is 70, and then for each sub-element in the row I expand the total row hieght by 60 * number of subelements - I only want height 0 - 70 to be 'selectable', the sub-members of the row should not be. How do you do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using touch events, but as you are already using `UITableView` it seems easier (and more *iPhonish*) to use what tables provides you:

```
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
etc.
```

Search a sample called "**Table View Animations and Gestures**" in the documentation. Just load the reference for `UITableView` and you'll see it on the bottom left corner sidebar.

To make non-selectable rows just change its cell `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.